# SAS University Edition with Virtual Box

Tags: sas, virtualbox, sas-studio

I followed all the steps are stayed in the video (http://www.sas.com/en_us/software/university-edition/download-software.html#windows)

After I click Start --> Normal Start I get the following errors

[image]

and immediately this error come up

[image]

Here is my configuration from the virtual box.

[image]

Thank you very much

Comment: What shows under details? You're much better posting these questions on communities.sas.com. Also, please look at the SAS UE Help Center, a lot of the common issues are detailed there. A common issue is virutalization not being supported.

Comment: I'm also assuming you set up your shared drive?

Answer (score 1):

You need 64bit Windows to make SAS UE to work.

Answer (score 0):

I got similar errors recently when upgrading to Virtualbox 5.x.x. The most recent version that worked for me was 4.3.36, which is available here:

https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Download_Old_Builds_4_3

Does that version work for you?

If not, I suggest you have a go at setting this up on AWS instead.